# Drop asm into an Existing JS Application

Tags: javascript, emscripten, asm.js

I got emscripten working, but it generates huge self executing files. Is it possible to make emscripten generate small functions that I want to optimize so I can copy paste them into my existing application easily?

Thanks!

Comment: How about creating a module and exporting it and then importing and calling it from within your js code?

Comment: Well, copy/paste isn't necessarily the method I prefer, it's more that the output is thousands of lines.

Comment: Where did you read any talk about copy paste? I'm asking this with hesitation, but do you even know what js modules are?

Comment: I do understand what modules are, but I was assuming that the core of the compiled code would be something that was small. I'm trying to understand the asmjs ecosystem. Does the output actually require thousands of lines, or is the non-boilerplate something can be analyzed by hand and run with minimal overhead? 

For instance, say I had an `int fib(int n) {...}` function. Could I compile an asm version of that and use it in my otherwise hand written javascript codebase?

This is intended to be used on the web, not in a standalone node.js installation. There's no support for browserify yet.

Comment: I should clarify what my use case is... we're running an experiment to run the marching cubes algorithm on client machines to generate 3D meshes from 3D images. I wanted to give asm a try to see if we could increase performance as it's almost acceptable performance right now.

Comment: You can use an lightweight alternative to emscripten, I can't suggest any but I have seen some out there. But from my limited experience, I believe that emscripten is the best in this field. The overhead is probably from included libraries and namespaces. You could try coping the code (but as you've said that can get annoying) w/o overhead to see if it works, it probably will if you don't call external resources. Or avoid any of these and see if it outputs less overhead. Maybe this issue can give you some more insight https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/2785.

Comment: Thanks Marko! I'll look around for the other lightweight ones and try manually copying if necessary... If you paste your answer into the answer field I'll give you some karma. :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: `bonsai-c` generates small asm.js. But it only supports limited subset of C. https://github.com/gasman/bonsai-c

Answer (score 2):

I would advise against a copy/paste of some generated function from the inside of the Emscripten-generated output unless you have identified that bandwidth / compiling of the ASM/Javascript in the browser is a limiting factor that affects the performance of the application. Going down that route I suspect makes would make updates full of pain that I would avoid unless necessary.

What I think is better is to use the techniques in the [Code Size section of the Emscripten docs](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/optimizing/Optimizing-Code.html#code-size)

Some of the fairly straightforward ways are:

- Using [NO_FILESYTEM](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/1.35.17/src/settings.js#L362) to prod Emscripten to not include some standard libraries (assuming you don't need them).
- Using [NO_BROWSER](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/1.35.17/src/settings.js#L366) if you can
- Using [NO_EXIT_RUNTIME](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/1.35.17/src/settings.js#L36) to not include some functions required when exiting.
- Tinkering with the optimization flags, but according to [the docs](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/tools_reference/emcc.html#emcc-o2) `-O2` offers

  > the smallest and fastest output.

Comment: 2018 update, I think these options are now encapsulated into -s ENVIRONMENT= one of 'web', 'worker', 'shell', or 'node'. The previous advice was for version 1.35.7, this advice is for 1.38.6

https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/1.38.6/src/settings.js

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but not well documented yet: you can use the `--separate-asm` flag. See

https://gist.github.com/wycats/4845049dcf0f6571387a

and

https://gist.github.com/kripken/910bfe8524bdaeb7df9a

for examples.